# Send API get request from AWS Lambda in ruby

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, timeout, httprequest

I was trying to send API request to my rails server from AWS Lambda function.

I was using [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem to send request.

I have tried with below code

```
require "httparty"

class PostManager
  include HTTParty

  def initialize
  end

  def create_post(job_id)
    puts "----------------- Inside post manager ------------------"
    puts "----------------- #{ENV["BASE_URI"]} ------------------"
    puts "#{ENV['BASE_URI']}/call_response?job_id=#{job_id}"
    response = HTTParty.get("#{ENV['BASE_URI']}")
    puts "******************HTTP Response -: #{response}******************"
    response
  end
end
```

I am triggering this code from aws lambda main handler like below.

```
post_manager = PostManager.new
response     = post_manager.create_post(job_id)
```

But lambda function gets timeout. Request not reaching to rails server at all.

Please guide me if i am missing something. Other alternatice to send post request to external server from aws lambda function is also invited.

Comment: Is the Lambda function deployed in a VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Since http party is a http client, I recommend read the [documentation](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), start experimenting with pry and a site like http://httpbin.org

So went will have all the thinks. reading your code I'm not sure of what you want to achieve, but I think that you want to connect to some en point that is on:

The domain inside this shell variable => #{ENV['BASE_URI']}
the path of the http method => call_response
and some path parameters like => job_id=#{job_id}

You allways say that this is a post but you are doing a get => `HTTParty.get`

So let's start with some object like the one showed in [the documentation](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty#examples) in order to attack to [this method](http://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/get_get) with curl will be something like this:

```
❯ curl -X GET "http://httpbin.org/get?job_id=4" -H  "accept: application/json"                                                                                                           ~/learn/ruby/stackoverflow
{
  "args": {
    "job_id": "4"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.64.1",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-613b73ef-2d00166a2ae40e704b448352"
  },
  "origin": "83.53.251.55",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?job_id=4"
}
```

Then for an http client object

add this to afile called httpbin_client.rb :

```
require 'httparty'

class HTTPbinClient
  include HTTParty
  base_uri ENV['BASE_URI']

  def initialize
  end

  def ask_for_job_id(job_id)
    self.class.get('/get', {query: {job_id: job_id}})
  end
end

http_bin = HTTPbinClient.new
puts http_bin.ask_for_job_id(28)
```

call like this:

```
❯ BASE_URI=httpbin.org ruby httpbin_client.rb                                 ~/learn/ruby/stackoverflow
{
  "args": {
    "job_id": "28"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Ruby",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-613b776d-47036b9b29bb1ae34b4a0e50"
  },
  "origin": "83.53.251.55",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?job_id=28"
}
```